# Image not shared on Facebook while clicking Facebook share button

Tags: facebook-share, share-button

When a user clicks on the Facebook share then I want to share an image which is linked "og:image "button but not a share this image

I have added some meta tags for the Facebook share button as mentioned below.

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="https://www.mydomain.co/" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="website" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="KIWI" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="How much does culture influence creative thinking?" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="https://www.mydomain.co/KiwiSite/img/hero-bg.png" />
<meta property=" og:image:width "              content="650" />
<meta property="og:image:height"              content="315" />
<meta property="og:image:alt"              content="Not found image" />
```

I have following below link

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/

Anyone have idea how to share an image which we have applied on "og:image" tag.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your code should work fine.  Here's the meta property tag from my website...

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.RevoltLib.com/image/revolt-lib.jpg">
```

Here is the share URL...

> [Share RevoltLib.com on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.revoltlib.com)

And here is the result:

[image]

***Works great!***

If you're still not sure, why not check out the [Official Facebook Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/).  This should give you more useful information about problems in your URL.  For instance, the status seems to be good for the URL we've been sharing so far...

> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=revoltlib.com